# Iterate over chunks of date range in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def forward_date_range(start_dt, end_dt, span_days):
    #
    # Generate tuples with intervals from given range of dates (forward)
    #
    # forward_date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-01-5', 2)
    #
    # 1st yield = ('2012-01-01', '2012-01-03')
    # 2nd yield = ('2012-01-04', '2012-01-05')
    start_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_dt   = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
    span     = datetime.timedelta(days=span_days)
    step     = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    while start_dt + span < end_dt:
        current = start_dt + span
        yield start_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        start_dt = current + step
    else:
        yield start_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

def backward_date_range(start_dt, end_dt, span_days):
    #
    # Generate tuples with intervals from given range of dates (backward)
    #
    # backward_date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-01-5', 2)
    #
    # 1st yield = ('2012-01-03', '2012-01-05')
    # 2nd yield = ('2012-01-01', '2012-01-02')
    start_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_dt   = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_dt, '%Y-%m-%d')
    span     = datetime.timedelta(days=span_days)
    step     = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    while end_dt - span > start_dt:
        current = end_dt - span
        yield current.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        end_dt = current - step
    else:
        yield start_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), end_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

This is currently what I have, needless to say it looks ugly. Is there a more elegant solution, especially if it is possible to get rid of the `while` loop altogether? or maybe compress it into one single line?

I am currently using `python3.5`

Comment: Hi, you might be able to get better reviews by providing a bit more context. Can you add a bit of explanation of why you need such feature and/or some code calling these functions?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger its a helper function that is used to supply start and end "range subsets" to SQL queries that wouldve clogged up a network. Something like "1996-2016" is split into smaller chunks for convenience

Comment: @Alan: Surely adding `LIMIT` to the SQL queries would have been a better solution to this problem?

Comment: @GarethRees The data structure of this case prevents this

Comment: FYI, relational databases usually perform better if you give them one big query rather than requesting the same rows via many component queries. That is to say, it's better to let the DB do the looping than to have your loop generate related queries. Why? A single big query lets the backend planner see the future, lets it optimize access paths across _all_ result rows rather than just the rows of a component query. Depending on the DB vendor, daily partitions of a large table can be an attractive approach. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the corner cases are what you want, i.e. a date
"range" of a single day is acceptable - otherwise you'd have to overhaul
the calculation a bit.

I'm not going to attempt to remove the `while` loops - I don't know a
better alternative; six lines self-contained logic each isn't too bad
IMO.

First things first, I'd recommend a couple of things for better
readability and interactivity:

- Use proper docstrings instead of comments, so that both tools and
  human readers know what the functions are about.  At the moment
  `help(forward_date_range)` isn't too helpful, but with that change it
  would be much more so.
- Similarly, the `_dt` suffix isn't that readable either.  I'd either
  drop it or expand it to `_date` so that it's more obvious.

Next, I'd try to remove some more duplication:

- The string `'%Y-%m-%d'` comes up a total of twelve times.  Either put
  that into a constant (if you don't ever want users to supply a
  different format), or make it an optional function parameter.
- The structure of both functions is also quite similar, so while the
  loop might not be worth to factor out, the pre- and postprocessing
  definitely is.  Also, `timedelta(days=1)` is another constant in the
  code.
- Importing the right names (e.g. `datetime` and `timedelta`) could also
  cut down the number of tokens to read.
- There's also an opportunity to cache the result of `end - span` into a
  separate variable so as to not repeat it in every loop.
- (From @mathias-ettinger) The loop doesn't have a `break` to exit it
  early, so the `else` branch will always be executed.  In that case it
  makes sense to just put it on its own line without the `else` which
  doesn't change the meaning in any respect.

Lastly, I'd probably say that the conversion from and to `datetime`
objects doesn't belong into these functions and should be done
separately instead.  If you want to keep it like it is there are still
some opportunities for helper functions to cut down the noise.

The result I'm posting below can still be compressed further, but at
that point it would be generally getting more functional and less like
regular Python code.

So there we have it:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
DATE_STEP = timedelta(days=1)


def _strptime(string):
    return datetime.strptime(string, DATE_FORMAT)


def _strftime(date):
    return date.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)


def _date_range_parameters(start, end, span_days):
    start = _strptime(start)
    end   = _strptime(end)
    span  = timedelta(days=span_days)
    return start, end, span


def forward_date_range(start, end, span_days):
    """
    Generate tuples with intervals from given range of dates (forward).

    forward_date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-01-5', 2)

    1st yield = ('2012-01-01', '2012-01-03')
    2nd yield = ('2012-01-04', '2012-01-05')
    """
    start, end, span = _date_range_parameters(start, end, span_days)
    stop = end - span

    while start < stop:
        current = start + span
        yield _strftime(start), _strftime(current)
        start = current + DATE_STEP

    yield _strftime(start), _strftime(end)


def backward_date_range(start, end, span_days):
    """
    Generate tuples with intervals from given range of dates (backward)

    backward_date_range('2012-01-01', '2012-01-5', 2)

    1st yield = ('2012-01-03', '2012-01-05')
    2nd yield = ('2012-01-01', '2012-01-02')
    """
    start, end, span = _date_range_parameters(start, end, span_days)
    stop = start + span

    while end > stop:
        current = end - span
        yield _strftime(current), _strftime(end)
        end = current - DATE_STEP

    yield _strftime(start), _strftime(end)
```